# Tikz : Increasing dot spacing along a curve

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have dotted line created from 3 points but I would like to have an increasing density of points along the curve. I managed to create a dot pattern but the spacing is fixed. In the general case I don't have the equation of the curve.

**Is this possible to control the density of points along the curve directly with tikz ?** Maybe with a function ?

```
\documentclass[8pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

% Dot pattern
\tikzset{
    dot diameter/.store in=\dot@diameter,
    dot diameter=2pt,
    dot spacing/.store in=\dot@spacing,
    dot spacing=3pt,
    dots/.style={
        line width=\dot@diameter,
        line cap=round,
        dash pattern=on 0pt off \dot@spacing
    }
}

\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (z) at (0.9,-1);
 
        % Dots along a curve
        \draw[draw=black,dots] plot [smooth,tension=1] coordinates { ($(z)+(-0.5,-1)$) ($(z)+(0.1,-0.5)$) ($(0,0)$) };

        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Thank you !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this can be done. Below are two options: either you pass the positions to a list, or you define a function for the spacing. The syntax for the second option is

```
variable dots={<function>}{<samples>}
```

e.g.

```
variable dots={2*\x/(10+\x)}{1,...,7}
```

where the function is, by default, a function of `\x`. The code is annotated. It also avoids `dimension too large` errors by using `fpu`.

```
\documentclass[8pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.markings,fpu}

\tikzset{dot diameter/.initial=2pt,
add marking position/.code={\edef\x{#1}%
\pgfmathparse{spacingfunction(\x)}%
\ifx\mymarkpositions\empty
\edef\mymarkpositions{\pgfmathresult}
\else
\edef\mymarkpositions{\mymarkpositions,\pgfmathresult}%
\fi},variable dots/.code 2 args={%
\tikzset{declare function={spacingfunction(\x)=#1;}}%
\let\mymarkpositions\empty%
\tikzset{add marking position/.list={#2}}%
%\typeout{\mymarkpositions}
\tikzset{postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,%
my mark/.list/.expanded={\mymarkpositions}}}}}}
\tikzset{/pgf/decoration/my mark/.code=\tikzset{/pgf/decoration/mark={at position #1 with 
    {\fill circle[radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/dot diameter}];}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \coordinate (z) at (0.9,-1);
 % Dots along a curve
 \draw[/pgf/fpu/install only={reciprocal},%<- only to avoid "dimension too large" errors
    draw=black,postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,
    my mark/.list={0.18181,0.33333,0.46153,0.57143,0.66666,0.75,0.82352}%<- explicit list
    }}] 
    plot [smooth,tension=1] coordinates 
 { ($(z)+(-0.5,-1)$) ($(z)+(0.1,-0.5)$) ($(0,0)$) };
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \coordinate (z) at (0.9,-1);
 % Dots along a curve
 \draw[/pgf/fpu/install only={reciprocal},%<- only to avoid "dimension too large" errors
    draw=black,variable dots={2*\x/(10+\x)}%<- function
    {1,...,7}]%<- arguments 
    plot [smooth,tension=1] coordinates 
 { ($(z)+(-0.5,-1)$) ($(z)+(0.1,-0.5)$) ($(0,0)$) };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much ! But is it possible to not actually draw the curve ? I would like only the dots.

Comment: @so-orange Sure. One way is to replace `draw=black` by `draw=none`. (Or remove the `postaction` key, but I think that the first option is the easiest way to make this happen in the above code.)

Comment: Thank you very much ! I feel a bit stupid to not have thought about that!